# pre tag different in browsers

Tags: html, css, word-wrap, pre

So I have this code:

```
<span readonly="true" id="textarea" cols="60" rows="1">
  <pre style="{display:inline; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap:break-word;}"> SOME TEXT HERE </pre>
</span>
```

I have two problems. one when i introduce a very long string without spaces or newlines. example:

> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.

On firefox and opera it shows normal:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

etc.

on chrome, IE and safari it shows:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

and exits the screen

I need some help. 
Oh and the second problem is that on chrome, IE and safari instead of showing inline, it shows block even though i wrote display:inline;

**SOLVED: instead of  I used  so it would be inline from the start. And just like you guys said I took out {} and it worked! Thank you**

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. Can you provide a real-world example of this with some code?

Comment: @MetalFrog Code was present, but just hidden due to bad formating.

Comment: surely it should be <pre style="display:inline; white-space:pre-wrap;"></pre> ?

Comment: Why are you putting `{}` characters into style?

Comment: Thanks you Sam and bažmegakapa.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect it's because you have not defined a width, and in my experience `word-wrap` only works on block elements (you can set `inline-block` if you need it to wrap and be inline).

It's also bizarre that you're placing a `pre` within a `span` that has attributes of a `textarea`.

http://jsfiddle.net/A2MNN/

**HTML:**

```
<pre>
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.
</pre>
```

**CSS**

```
pre{
    width:40em;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    white-space:pre-wrap;
}
```

Comment: the span was a textarea long time ago. I just never changed the attributes. Anyway it doesn't work. it works on firefox to set the width but not on chrome.

Comment: Works in Chrome for me. Does the fiddle work, but not your page?

Answer (score 1):

Your markup is invalid, in a manner that browsers are not prepared to handle, and your style sheet violates CSS rules. This means that you should expect browsers to display garbage, possible different garbage on different browsers.

To get help with your real problem, you should describe the problem (not a completely broken way of solving an unspecified problem), i.e. what you would like to achieve, and show your best attempt at solving it, as a complete and valid HTML document.